# Want to count occurrence, then only print count values which are higher than the average of all counted values

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I was trying to count the number of times a patient went to the hospital for each of the available 10 patients (including those who does not went at all, for no good reason), but only wanting to print the ones whose visit count is higher than the average of all recorded visit counts.
How can I do this, when I can't compare any count values in the WHERE and HAVING clauses, and can't precalculate the average first the compare to it later). Please help

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: That's a lot of "can't"s - are you saying because you don't know how or because you're not allowed to do it?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't know how to do these

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you be more specific? I'm pretty new into the language so I'm gonna need all the help I can. Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry I don't even know how to write the program to begin with though....

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're looking for something like :

```
SELECT
  patientid,
  count(*)
FROM visits 
GROUP BY patientid
HAVING count(*) > 
  (SELECT AVG(ct) FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) ct FROM visits GROUP BY patientid) x
  )
```

Visits might have to be upgraded to a left join between patient (on the left) and visits if there are patients who have never visited and you want their zeros to influence the average